# Transitioning multiple child elements with one <transition> wrapper

Tags: vue.js, vuejs-transition

I want to set multiple transitions (on separate child elements) inside one parent `v-if` state change.

For example when I display a modal I want the background blur to `fadeIn` (using opacity) and the modal content to `slideIn` (using transition or animation). My current situation is the following, when I use the transition the background blur element (`.modal`) is transitioning along with the content (`.modal__content`):

```
<transition enter-active-class="animated slideInRight" leave-active-class="animated slideOutRight">
  <div class="modal" v-if="isVisible">
    <div class="modal__content">
      </slot><slot/>
    </div>
  </div>
</transition>
```

Comment: korun, can you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: Haven't found anything useful at the time, the best way was to have a more JS based approach as its described in the answer below. I am working with React in the past year so I am probably out of date :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [JS hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks) after the `.modal` fades in to trigger the slide animation:

```
<template>
  <transition name="fade" @after-enter="showContent = true">
    <div class="modal" v-if="isVisible">
      <transition name="slide">
        <div class="modal__content" v-if="showContent">
        </div>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            isVisible: false,
            showContent: false
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry I am late to respond. While interesting solution, I was looking for a parallel transitions of the elements, which I managed to implement using the `appear` property of the transition element.

Also there are two caveats for this types of solutions - the code is verbose and there is not leave animation.

Comment: @korun, if you found a satisfying solution, please [post it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so others may benefit from it as well :)